# Restrict authentication method for endpoints with Spring Security

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, token, basic-authentication

I want to secure a REST API. The rules are simple.

- The user must call `/api/authenticate` to get a token
- The user can use a token (received from `/api/authenticate`) to access the API `/api/**`
- The endpoint `/api/authenticate` only accepts HTTP Basic authentication (no token authentication)
- The endpoints `/api/**` (excluding `/api/authenticate`) only accepts token authentication (no Basic Authentication)
- All remaining endpoints are public and doesn't require authentication.

I actually use this:

```
    @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider;

        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            httpSecurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            httpSecurity.headers().disable();
            httpSecurity.setSharedObject(TokenAuthenticationProvider.class, this.tokenAuthenticationProvider);
            httpSecurity.antMatcher("/api/authenticate").httpBasic();
            httpSecurity.antMatcher("/api/**").apply(new TokenAuthenticationConfigurer());
            httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll();
        }
    }
```

Actually, if I send a request with a token to `/api/authenticate` my configuration accepts the request. I think this happens because `/api/authenticate` is part of `/api/**`. So I need to exclude this path for token authentication.

How can I do that?

**EDIT 1**

If I use the `.and()` fluent style, the result is exactly the same.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.setSharedObject(TokenAuthenticationProvider.class, this.tokenAuthenticationProvider);
        httpSecurity
                .headers().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .antMatcher("/api/authenticate").httpBasic()
                .and()
                .antMatcher("/api/**").apply(new TokenAuthenticationConfigurer())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

As I understand the `SecurityBuilder` (`HttpSecurity`), every call of `antMatcher(...)` in the `configure(...)` method overwrites the previous call. In the debug logs I can see, that Spring Security always tries to match the request path against `/api/**` but never agains `/api/authenticate`. If I switch the order, I can't access the API anymore, just `/api/authenticate`, because Spring Security now always tries to match agains `/api/authenticate`.

So the question is: How can I register multiple rules:

- `/api/authenticate` -> `HttpBasicConfigurer` (`.http()`)
- `/api/**` -> `TokenAuthenticationConfigurer` (my token authentication configured, `.apply(...)`)

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue ?

Comment: Yes. You have to create multiple security configurations by extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. One configuration for `/api/authenticate` and another one for `/api/**`. Each of them can be configured with the desired security mechanism. You also have to use `@Order` to define the priority of your security configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because you always override the configuration of the parent and you do not use the `and()` method:

> The Java Configuration equivalent of closing an XML tag is expressed using the and() method which allows us to continue configuring the parent. If you read the code it also makes sense. I want to configure authorized requests and configure form login and configure HTTP Basic authentication.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-httpsecurity